# JavaScript Creating a Table dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a table using JS with random number of rows. The table does create, rows are being inserted outside of the 'for' loop, but when I place rows creation inside the loop, it doesn't create them:

```
function createTable (rn){
   var table.document.createElement("table");
   document.getElementById("anchor").appendChild(table);
   for(var r=0;r<rn;r++){
      var tr=table.insertRow(r); 
      var td1=tr.insertCell(0), td2=tr.insertCell(1);
      td1.innerHTML = "td1";
      td2.innerHTML = "td2";      
   }
}
```

Comment: so your question is how to add row-creation in your for-loop. can you show your code where you tried it yourself?

Comment: What error it shows on console?

Comment: Works fine once you resolve the syntax error.

Comment: A syntax error checker like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or the like can help you catch these kind of errors.

Comment: Thanks, Emil! I have found the error message on browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code `(var table.document.createElement("table");)`, From same code I am able to create table dynamically

```js
function createTable (rn){
   var table = document.createElement("table");
   document.getElementById("anchor").appendChild(table);
   for(var r=0;r<rn;r++){
      var tr=table.insertRow(r); 
      var td1=tr.insertCell(0), td2=tr.insertCell(1);
      td1.innerHTML = "td1";
      td2.innerHTML = "td2";      
   }
}
createTable(5);
```

```html
<div id="anchor"></div>
```

Comment: sriharsha_bhat, thanks, I was not attentive. There was a syntax error. Now it works well!